# Automation Java - Android - How to get items from a ListView?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, android, appium

I'm trying to get the items from a ListView so I can compare them with of expected results. The thing is that I can't figure out how to get those Elements.

I'm also the developer of the App, so I'm using the ID that I assigned to that element to identify it.

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
public String playersListItem(int n){
    //waitElement(driver.findElement(By.id("playersList")));
    List<WebElement> players = driver.findElements(By.id("playersList"));
    return players.get(n).getText();
}
```

I'm comparing `playersListItem(0)` with "Jones" but the item in the position 0 is always blank.

this is the reason of the fail that I get in the Assert:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Jones] but found []

Comment: [You may want to take a look at this question and its answers](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/12029/18919)

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one element with an ID of "playersList" so you won't get a set of elements from that item.  You first need to grab the outside element, the one with ID and then grab the elements inside that element.  Assuming that this is an un-ordered list it would look like this

```
public String playersListItem(int n){
    WebElement ulElement = driver.findElement(By.id("playersList"));
    List<WebElement> listOfPlayers = ulElement.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    return players.get(n).getText();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get all the TextViews from a list you can do something like this:

```
List<AndroidElement> textViews = ad.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.TextView");
            for (WebElement textView : textViews) {
                        return textView.getText();
                    }
```